# Titanium appcelerator android and ios platform height in pixels and dp

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am about to test an app with the appcelerator titanium framework, i have to center a view on the screen :

**my index.xml :**

```
<Alloy>
<!-- Anddroid Window -->
<Window id="index" platform="android">
    <Require type="view" id="firstscreen" src="firstscreen"/>
</Window>

<!-- iOS Window -->
<NavigationWindow id="nav" platform="ios">
    <Window id="win1" backgroundColor="white">
        <Require type="view" id="firstscreen" src="firstscreen"/>
    </Window>
</NavigationWindow>
```

**the firstscreen xml :**

```js
<Alloy>
 <ScrollView scrollingEnabled="false" contentWidth="Ti.UI.FILL">
  <ImageView class="fullBgImage" image="/images/login/bg2.png" />
  <View layout="vertical">
   <View id="loginView" class="heightAuto" layout="vertical">
    <ImageView id="localImage" image="/images/logo.png"  />
    <Label class="logoLabel" text="Karma" />
    <Label class="logoSlogan" text="Faits confiance à votre Karma pour booster votre carrière" />
    <View class="btn btnVert"  onClick="openCandidat"><Label class="btnLabel" text="Je recherche un job" /></View>
    <View class="btn btnBlanc" ><Label class="btnLabel bleu" text="Je suis recruteur" /></View>
   </View>
  </View>
 </ScrollView>
</Alloy>
```

**The index.js :**
    **The formula to achieve is : viewTopPosition = (platformheight - viewheight)/2**

```js
if (OS_ANDROID) {
 $.index.addEventListener('open', after_win_load);
 $.index.open();
} else {
 $.nav.addEventListener('open', after_win_load);
 $.nav.open();
}

function after_win_load() {
 // Platform height
 var platformHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
 // The view
 var firstscreen = $.firstscreen;
 /* Taille du logo */
 firstscreenViewHeight = firstscreen.loginView.size;
 /* Centrer la vue verticalement */
 firstScreenTop = platformHeight - firstscreenViewHeight.height;
 //firstscreen.top = firstScreenTop;
 
 var style = $.createStyle({
  classes : 'firstScreenTop',
  apiName : 'View',
  top : firstScreenTop / 2
 });

 firstscreen.loginView.applyProperties(style);
}
```

On iOs it looks great, view is centered vertically, but in android the : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight is a too big pixels value = 1920

on my tiapp.xml file i already specified :

```js
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

I know that android is pixels unit but iOs use dp unit, so how i to achieve this please ? someone has an idea?
For now for android i replaced the

```js
var platformHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
```

to

```js
var platformHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi;
```

But i ask myself if it will be good for all android screen resolution? and if this is a best practice?

Thank for your helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var densityFactor = OS_IOS ? 1 : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor;

 var platformHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / densityFactor;
```

or you can directly set the top to 50%

```
var style = $.createStyle({
    classes : 'firstScreenTop',
    apiName : 'View',
    top : "50%"
});
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for response, setting the top directly to 50% will not center the view but push it to 50% from the screen top, or i am wrong?

Comment: 1) `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor` is available on iOS as well in recent SDKs. 2) indeed this will push it 50% down. 3) The default in a (default) composite/absolute layout is for children to be centered.

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you very much.